# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This part of code is pasted in my `order.php` template file.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/page/order_ajax'); ?>', {}, function(data)) {
        $('#orderResult').html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

his job is calling my `order_ajax` function witch is in my page controller, but I got error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

and don't redirect me on that page. I'm don't know too good jquery and ajax, maybe it's a small error xD

Comment: Please post the **generated** HTML/JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly what it says. "Unexpected token )". There is a close-parenthesis that is unexpected.

Most likely, your issue exists here: `function(data)) {`

Why are there two close-parentheses there? Try removing one of them:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/page/order_ajax'); ?>', {}, function(data) {
        $('#orderResult').html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra close parenthesis after `function(data)` that doesn't belong there...